# Shell script to parse data in columns

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I require some help with a homework question. I have the following data in a file that I need to parse:

```
              Output-------------------------- Input---------------- Random----
              -Per Char- --Block--- -Rewrite-- -Per Char- --Block--- --Seeks---
Machine    MB K/sec %CPU K/sec %CPU K/sec %CPU K/sec %CPU K/sec  %CPU /sec  %CPU
         50.0 36112 34.1 138026  1.9 179048  7.0 51361 51.1 312242  4.3 15211.4 10.3
```

What I need is a way to extract the data from the Block column for both the output and input columns. For example:

```
Output Block:
K/sec: 138026
%CPU:  1.9

Input Block:
K/sec: 312242
%CPU:  4.3
```

I am limited to using sed, awk, cut, and grep.

Comment: Sounds like fun, but what have you tried?

Comment: I've tried grep but that's only giving me the row. I'm looking for a way to get the column. So I've tried things like

grep -e "--Block---"

Comment: Sounds like you have a sadistic instructor; what have you tried?  I don't think you're going to be able to, or want to, write a general purpose tool.  You'll end up with a script customized to the peculiarities of the layout you show.

Comment: On line 3, you need columns 5, 6, 11, 12; on line 4 (and following?) you need columns 4, 5, 10, 11.  `awk` is good for getting columns.

Comment: I'll take a look into awk. Sadistic would be a nice term to describe my instructor.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: `awk -F" +"` (and that behaviour is defined by Posix)

Comment: I've been working on parsing Output and have the following so far:

'code'
cat someinputfile | grep "Sequential Output" | awk '{ print $1 " " $2}'


cat someinputfile | grep "%CPU" | awk '{ print $3 " " $4}'

Comment: How do I format code tags in a reply comment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

parse_data.txt:- Is the file where the data is present.

more parse_data.txt | grep -v "-"  | sed 's/\      /\    /g' | awk '{print  $4 " "$5 " " $10 " " $11}'

CPU and k/sec data with respect Output and Input block 
is been retrieved, as shown below,

**Output got is:**

```
 K/sec  %CPU K/sec  %CPU
 138026 1.9  312242 4.3
```

Hope this solves your problem!!!!!

Comment: So actually just `awk '!/-/{print  $4 " "$5 " " $10 " " $11}' parse_data.txt` then. The Useless Use of More in particular is ... bold.

Answer (score 0):

because of the odd headers only the data line has 13 fields, so you can just use an awk one-liner:

```
awk '{if (NF==13) printf "Output Block:\nK/sec: %s\n%CPU:  %s\n\nInput Block:\nK/sec: %s\n%CPU:  %s\n",$4, $5, $10, $11 }' inputfilename
```

and if you want to parse multiple lines in a shell

```
while read LINE || [ "$LINE" ]; do ... done < inputfile
```

to split up a string you can use read again like

```
read dummyvar dummyvar2 dummy3 outputkb ... <<< $mystring
```